# Update base controller variable values but all derived controllers are not updated in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my `BaseController`:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public Int64 CompanyId { get; set; } // I need to update this property
}
```

I have another 2 controllers, `CompanyController`:

```
public class CompanyController : BaseController
{
   
    public IActionResult ChangeCompany(long CompanyId = 35)  //
    {   
        base.CompanyId = CompanyId;
        // other code
    }

    public IActionResult GetCompany()  //
    {   
        return base.CompanyId  // return 35
    }
}
```

and `AccountController`:

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    public IActionResult GetCompany()  //
    {   
        return base.CompanyId  // return 0
    }
}
```

How can I get the updated `CompanyId` value from `AccountController`?

Comment: not. because your AccountController and CompanyController are _different instance_ - with theit _own_ value for CompanyId. you should move that functionality in a service that both contorllers use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Each object is different and the base class is just a template that your other classes extend. Every `new` object will create and maintain their own `CompanyId` variable, so you can't and shouldn't change the one by changing the other.

Check the `static` keyword if you want one value only for all the classes `public  static Int64 CompanyId { get; set; }`

Basically this:

```
public class CompanyController : BaseController
{
   
    public IActionResult ChangeCompany(long CompanyId = 35)  //
    {   
        base.CompanyId = CompanyId;
        // other code
    }

    public IActionResult GetCompany()  //
    {   
        return base.CompanyId  // return 35
    }

}
```

Is the same as this (though without inheritance, you can't even know which parts the two classes have in common):

```
public class CompanyController
{
    public Int64 CompanyId { get; set; } // I need to update this property
    public IActionResult ChangeCompany(long CompanyId = 35)  //
    {   
        base.CompanyId = CompanyId;
        // other code
    }

    public IActionResult GetCompany()  //
    {   
        return base.CompanyId  // return 35
    }

}
```